# How to insert multiple values in one row in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, delimiter

I'm going to make a tbrecord database to keep user data, let says my record table contains

1. record_id
2. member_id
3. relation
4. date

BEFORE
(Record01, M001, ... , 20-11-2014)

but the value is'nt from the query, I've an array in session (php).
my values
r001
r002
r003
r004

If it's possible,
I would like to insert multiple values to relation field, with ',' delimiter.

like this,

AFTER

*(Record01, M001, (r001,r002,r003,r004), 20-11-2014)*

thank you in advance. :)

Comment: read about 1NF on wikipedia

Comment: is there a fixed number of values? I mean its always just 4 item?

Comment: @Ahmad no it's not a fixed number.

Comment: this sounds like a problem that can be solved very simply with php than with a query.  A very simple for each loop can build the query.

Comment: @hjpotter92 sorry this is not about relational database. I've a quiz form and i need to store all of the answers for final record. or any better idea? :) thanks

Comment: I'd still say that it can be simplified by normalization.

Comment: Storing multiple values in a single database column is in most cases very bad choice, it makes querying that column troublesome, and leads to performacje problems, since each query must use conditions `column LIKE '%value%', which cannot use an index to speed up the query. Read about a database normalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another table to hold your values like `Relation(id,item,record_id)` the `record id` in this table is a foreign key which points to your original table `Records(record_id, member_id,date)`

Now you can insert each value by a query to the `Relation` table, there is no limit to the items, the `record_id` of all of them is equal to the `record_id` of the row in `Records` table which the relation belong to

Answer (score 1):

Storing multiple values like this in a single database cell isn't advisable and may come back to hurt you later on down the road but to do it is quite simple.

```
<?php

$yourPHParray = array('r001','r002','r003','r004');

$yourQueryString = '("Record01", "M001", "(\'';

foreach($yourPHParray as $singleValue)
{
$yourQueryString .= $singleValue."','";
}

$yourQueryString = substr($yourQueryString, 0,-2); // Remove trailing ,'

$yourQueryString .= ')", "20-11-2014")';

echo $yourQueryString;

?>
```

The echo will return exactly

("Record01", "M001", "('r001','r002','r003','r004')", "20-11-2014")

Hope this helps!

Comment: As the OP claims the number of relation items is not fixed this solution won't work. because it assumes fixed columns!!

Comment: He said the number of array elements was variable. Not the table structure. He explicitly states that the table columns are record_id, member_id, relation, date.